# Random errors show up when I insert a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors

When I include at the bottom of my latex file the code

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

I get the following errors in my Log file (note my Latex compiles with **no** errors when I don't include the code for my bibliography above) :

```
Line 7|!Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>$
L7...retexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/General_Relativity_Crowell/0 3%3A...
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

Line 10|! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.10
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed

Line 10|! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.10
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

Line 10| ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\par ...m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }
\fi
l.10
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

This is my preamble which starts at line 1:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{url}

\author{}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{pos}{Postulate}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
```

I find these errors very confusing and I don't know why including the two lines of code for the bibliography throws these errors up.

Here's my Bibtex file:

```
@misc{Sinc,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    date-added = {2022-04-13 14:48:25 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-13 14:48:36 +0100},
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Sinc\%20function&oldid=1073413879}},
    note = {[Online; accessed 13-April-2022]},
    title = {{Sinc function} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia},
    year = {2022}}

@book{ShankarTB,
    address = {New York, NY},
    author = {Shankar, Ramamurti},
    date-added = {2022-04-05 13:42:21 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-05 13:42:28 +0100},
    publisher = {Plenum},
    title = {{Principles of quantum mechanics}},
    year = {1980},

@misc{CoordIndependence,
    author = {Benjamin Crowell},
    date-added = {2022-04-04 16:45:37 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-04 16:49:50 +0100},
    url = {\url{https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/General_Relativity_(Crowell)/03%3A_Differential_Geometry/3.09%3A_Interpretation_of_Coordinate_Independence}},
    month = {March},
    note = {[Online; accessed 2022-04-04]},
    title = {Interpretation of {Coordinate} {Independence}},
    year = {2022}}

@book{FeynmanTB,
    address = {New York, NY},
    author = {Feynman, Richard Phillips and Hibbs, Albert Roach},
    date-added = {2022-04-03 18:17:18 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-03 18:57:56 +0100},
    publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
    series = {International series in pure and applied physics},
    title = {{Quantum mechanics and path integrals}},
    year = {1965}}
    
@misc{Sunny1,
    author = {Lu Hueng Sunny Yu},
    date-added = {2022-04-03 18:12:24 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-04 11:17:36 +0100},
    title = {Comment on the number of components we work with in different formalisms},
    year = {2022}}

@article{Dirac1933,
    author = {Dirac, Paul A. M.},
    date-added = {2022-04-03 18:08:30 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-03 18:08:40 +0100},
    journal = {Phys. Z. Sowjetunion},
    pages = {64--72},
    title = {{The Lagrangian in quantum mechanics}},
    volume = {3},
    year = {1933}}

@misc{Path_integral_formulation,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    date-added = {2022-04-03 17:25:31 +0100},
    date-modified = {2022-04-13 14:48:33 +0100},
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Path\%20integral\%20formulation&oldid=1054653277}},
    note = {[Online; accessed 03-April-2022]},
    title = {{Path integral formulation} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia},
    year = {2022}}

@article{FeynmanPopular,
    author = {Feynman, Richard P., and A. Zee},
    date-added = {2022-01-07 17:48:43 +0000},
    date-modified = {2022-01-07 17:49:41 +0000},
    title = {QED: the strange theory of light and matter.},
    year = {2006}}

@article{RiggedHilbert,
    author = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space}},
    date-added = {2022-01-06 15:54:05 +0000},
    date-modified = {2022-01-06 15:54:37 +0000},
    title = {Rigged Hiilbert Space}}
```

Comment: You have some special (special for LaTeX, anyway) characters in some of the URLs of your entries. Use `\url{...}` around URLs, then hopefully things should work (plus you will get a working link if you load `\usepackage{hyperref}`). If not, please show us the `.bib` entry containing `retexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/General_Relativity_Crowell`.

Comment: @moewe I believe I have done that. I've included my Bibtex file in the edited post above

Comment: Don't put the URL into the `author` field (as in `RiggedHilbert`) that will blow up. You are also missing a closing curly brace in the entry `ShankarTB`. There are a few other warnings when you run BibTeX on your file that you should fix (mostly empty `journal` warnings, because some entries should not be `@article`s).

Comment: got it fixed thank you